# DBCC SHRINKFILE EMPTYFILE stucked because of sysfiles1 table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, data-migration

I'm trying to migrate my pretty big db on SQLServer 2008 from one drive to another with minimum downtime and have some issues.

So , basically, my plan is to use DBCC SHRINKFILE ('filename', EMPTYFILE) for extent movement.
After some period of time, I shrink this file to avoid some space problems with log shipping db's in other server.
Huge amount of extents were moved successfully, but then I've got this error

DBCC SHRINKFILE: System table SYSFILES1 Page 1:21459450 could not be moved to other files because it only can reside in the primary file of the database.
Msg 2555, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Cannot move all contents of file "filename" to other places to complete the emptyfile operation.
DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.

So, what I've tried already:

- manually make my db bigger by adding empty space(just make file bigger by altering database)
- work a little bit with files in SECONDARY filegroup
- work with db after full\transactional backup

And this didn't work.
Can someone help me to fix this?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message states, there are some things that need to reside in the PRIMARY filegroup. Use the information in sys.allocation_units to find out what user (as opposed to system) objects are still in PRIMARY and move them with `create index … with (drop_existing = on) on OTHER_FILEGROUP`. Once you've moved all of your objects, you should be able to shrink the file down to as small as it can possibly be. Your final step will be to incur the downtime to move the primary file (in this case, minimal downtime does not mean "no downtime"). Luckily, what actually needs to reside in PRIMARY isn't very much data, so the downtime should be small. But you'll have a good idea once you get everything out of there.

While you're at it, set the default filegroup for your database to something other than primary to avoid putting user objects there in the future.